# I want to use standalone python3 package which can be just copy and use and need not to be install

Tags: python-3.x

can some please help me to provide link to download standalone binary package of python3, I just want copy and use it.

Comment: Did you consider using something like anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

like the packages on the python.org site?
https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: this link has installable python, my requirement is download and use without instaling